# Positioning a child div outside of parent div

Tags: html, css

i have a table that have tooltip on mouseover, i would like to show 20px x 20px outside of the parent div

so for example if the cell is on the top left quarter of the table it the top tooltip appear 20 px below the bottom of the cell and 20 px to the right this works awesome, but i can't figure how to make the rest work properly, how can i go above or on the left of a div, ex, how can i make my div at the bottom right not over flow with the outside of the page.

i have tried this:

```
.HeatMapTooltip.rightHM.topHM{
  right:-115px;
  margin-bottom:-118px;
}
```

But with no success

This image is an example of the 4 quarters of my table.

[image: Example of cell position in table]

thank you in advance

https://jsfiddle.net/vnLxe23b/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make use of `margin-left` and `margin-top` rather than `right` and `bottom`.

The following should overwrite your existing rules:

```
.HeatMapTooltip.rightHM.topHM {
  margin-left: -154px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.HeatMapTooltip.leftHM.bottomHM {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: -114px;
}

.HeatMapTooltip.rightHM.bottomHM {
  margin-left: -154px;
  margin-top: -65px;
}
```

This can be seen working [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/athq4g2c/).

You may need to adjust the values to suit.

Comment: WHAT IS THIS SORCERY!!!??? i am sure i had tried it... but with lower value! thank you so much..... i've been stumbling on this for a while :)